# Python dictionary.get() default return not working

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a dictionary from string to list of strings. So I thought I would use dict.get()'s default value keyword argument as such:

```
read_failures = {}
for filename in files:
    try:
        // open file
    except Exception as e:
        error = type(e).__name__
        read_failures[error] = read_failures.get(error, []).append(filename)
```

So by the end I want read_failures to look something like:

```
{'UnicodeDecodeError':['234.txt', '237.txt', '593.txt'], 'FileNotFoundError': ['987.txt']}
```

I have to use the get() command because I get a KeyError otherwise and this should technically work. If I do this in the interpreter line by line it works. But for some reason, in the script, the read_failures.get(error, []) method is returning None as default instead of the empty list I've specified. Is there perhaps a version of Python where the default get return wasn't a thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Think about what `append` returns.

Comment: True. I'm an idiot :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other comments and answers have pointed out, your issue is that `list.append` returns `None`, and so you can't assign the result of your call back to the dictionary. However, if the list is already in the dictionary, you don't need to reassign it, since `append` will modify it in place.

So the question is, how can you add a new list to the dictionary only if there isn't one there already? A crude fix would be to use a separate `if` statement:

```
if error not in read_failures:
    read_failures[error] = []
read_failures[error].append(filename)
```

But this requires up to three lookups of the key in the dictionary, and we can do better. The `dict` class has a method named `setdefault` that checks if a given key is in the dictionary. If not, it will assign a given default value to the key. And in any case, the value in the dictionary will be returned. So, we can do the whole thing in one line:

```
read_failures.setdefault(error, []).append(filename)
```

Another alternative solution would be to use a `defaultdict` object (from the `collections` module in the standard library) instead of a normal dictionary. The `defaultdict` constructor takes a `factory` argument that will be called to create a default value any time a key is requested that doesn't exist yet.

So another implementation would be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

read_failures = defaultdict(list)
for filename in files:
    try:
        // open file
    except Exception as e:
        error = type(e).__name__
        read_failures[error].append(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

So this

```
read_failures[error] = read_failures.get(error, []).append(filename)
```

sets the value of read_failures[error] to None because the .append method returns a None. Simple fix is to change this to:

```
read_failures[error] = read_failures.get(error, []) + [filename]
```

Thank you user2357112!